# magento - $ is not a function. But only on local dev server

Tags: magento

I took a backup of my live Magento site yesterday (zipped up the files and took a DB dump then created the site from those dumps).

Oddly though, on my local machine I get a firebug error that states "$ is not a function" and this error occurs every 500ms or so. So after a minute or 2 I have thousands of errors in the console all the same.

The site is an exact replica of my live site and I don't get the error on that so I'm stumped!

Usually I would think this is a prototype/jquery conflict, but it only seems to happen on my local machine.

Any one have a clue what might be going on?

Thanks

Comment: Needs more info. Is jQuery being loaded?

Comment: Thanks. Yes jQuery is being loaded. Prototype doesn't seem to be loading correctly though.

Comment: You should be getting an error in the Firebug console in the "Net" tab

Comment: No. No errors in the Net tab. Just errors in the Console ($ is not a function. element = $(element))

Comment: when using both libraries on the same page, you are using jQuery's `noConflict`, yes?

Comment: As mentioned above, this is an exact replica of my live server which is working correctly (with noconflict etc). It seems to fail on my local machine only. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, hard to diagnose without actually seeing it. How do you determine that Prototype doesn't seem to be loading correctly?

Comment: The add to cart button on the product view page doesn't work when clicked so I guess Prototype isn't loading correctly. Yea this is a head scratcher ok!

Comment: Do you have something loading via AJAX that may have an incorrect URL (pointing to a path that would be correct for the live server, but not yours maybe?), and then the error is a result of it not being able to load?

Comment: The repetitive timing of the errors could definitely point to an AJAX call. I'll investigate this a little more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this was the problem:

The reason it worked on live and not dev was because I had merge JS enabled on live and not on dev. Live was therefore looking at an old cached bunch of js. Disabling merge js on live highlighted that the problem did in fact occur on the live site.

This knowledge allowed me to debug further and I discovered that the problem lay with my jquery.hove.intent.js file. I updated this to the latest version and it solved everything! :)

Thanks all for your help and input though.

Answer (score 1):

Load a page where you see the error.

View the source of the page.

Find the line that's supposed to load `prototype.js` by searching for the string `prototype.js`.

```
ex. http://magento.example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js
```

Discover that, for one of myriad reasons, the file isn't loading. (wrong URL, permissions, corrupt file, etc.)

Address problem discovered above.

Comment: Thanks for your input Alan. The file appears to be loading correctly (I placed an alert at the start of the file and one at the end of the file). So it must be another reason I guess. I will continue in my quest